# How to align a textview with the "text" part of drawable TextView?

Tags: android, textview

I want to align the text `hello world` with the text `Medium Text`. Is there any trick that I can do that?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_favorite"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_hardware_keyboard_arrow_right"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello world"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/title"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: whats your requirements i mean what u want??

Comment: What do you mean by align? what position exactly?

Comment: your above code do same thing whtas problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any way to align where the text starts with layout_params alone. You can either change your layout to separate the images from the medium text, or you can use an identically sized (but completely transparent) image as the drawableLeft of the hello world text.

I would probably do something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_favorite"
        ... />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/image"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/title"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:text="hello world" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That is not what I want since the `detail` textview MUST below the image. I think I should do it through java code.

Comment: @sterio The detail will be below the image. It is below the title, and the title is baseline aligned with the image (you can use `alignBottom` instead if you feel that's better). Doing it in java will make no difference, except being more verbose and annoying to write/maintain. What you can do in java  is exactly the same as you can do in XML.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_favorite"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Medium Text">
            </TextView>

            <TextView  android:id="@+id/detail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello world">
            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I hope this can help you.